# Angular create new component with specific name

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to generate a new component with a name like: myApplication.html/css/ts. I'm using this command: ng generate component myApplication. The problem is that the resulted component has this name: my-application.html/css/ts. It's not myApplication as I want. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: you want to avoid '-' ? if you. have Capital in your name it will add it automatically so one thing is you can write in small letters.

Comment: by the way, default angular convention for naming components is with hyphen.